# How do I upgrade my Android OS from 2.2 to 2.3 on an HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update the OS in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/how-do-i-update-the-os-in-my-device)

I am carrying a HTC Desire. I want to upgrade the OS from Android 2.2 to Android 2.3. How do I upgrade the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Check out on this following forums

1. [modaco](http://android.modaco.com/forum/430-htc-desire-desiremodacocom/)
2. [Cyanogen](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/forum/42-htc-desire-gsm/)
3. [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=594)

Note:  Please ready instructions carefully before performing anything. You can break your phone. You have to do everything on your own risk